If $|G| = p^a q^b$ for $p$, $q$ prime, and $G$ has exactly one Sylow-$p$ subgroup $P$ and one Sylow-$q$ subgroup $Q$, then $G \cong P \times Q$
I am hoping to show that if $|G| = p^a q^b$ for $p$, $q$ prime, and $G$ has  exactly one Sylow-$p$ subgroup $P$ and one Sylow-$q$ subgroup $Q,$ then $G \cong P \times Q$.
Here's where I've gotten so far:
Since $P$ and $Q$ are Sylow subgroups, we have $|P| = p^a$ and $|Q| = q^b$. Suppose $g \in P\cap Q$. Then $|g|$ divides both $p^a$ and $q^b$, which forces $|g| = 1$, hence $g=e$, and we have $P \cap Q = \{e\}$. Now I was hoping to find an injective homomorphism $\phi: P \times Q \rightarrow G$. If such a homomorphism would exist, then $P \times Q$ would be isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$, and moreover it would have the same order as $G$, so it would be isomorphic to $G$.
My guess was to define $\phi$ by $(x,y) \mapsto xy$ with $x \in P$, $y \in Q$ and $xy$ considered as a product in $G$. $\phi$ is injective because if $xy = e$ then $y = x^{-1}$ and vice versa which implies that both $x,y$ are in $P \cap Q$, hence $(x,y) = e$. But $\phi$ does not seem to be a homomorphism in general when $G$ is non-abelian.
I would really appreciate a hint on how to move forward with this problem! I am especially unsure about how to use the fact that $G$ admits only one Sylow subgroup for each of $p$ and $q$.
Thanks in advance!

Do you know why $P$ and $Q$ are normal? What is the order of $PQ$?

Hint: Show that (or use it if known) if $H\unlhd G$, $K\unlhd G$ and $h\in H, k\in K$ then $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in K\cap H$. That result has been explained and used many times on the site already, do search also!

Ah, thanks to you both for your comments! Very helpful. I think I've got it, and will write up an answer. (:

Thanks very much to Steve D and Jyrki Lahtonen for their comments!
As it turns out, $\phi$ is a homomorphism. By Sylow II, any conjugate subgroup $gPg^{-1}$ is also a Sylow-$p$ subgroup, and similarly for $Q$, so we conclude from the uniqueness of $P$ and $Q$ that each is a normal subgroup of $G$. Consequently, if $x \in P$, $y \in Q$, we have that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \in P \cap Q$, because it can be seen as a product of an element of $P$ with the conjugate of an element of $P$, and same for $Q$. Since $P \cap Q$ is just the trivial subgroup, this forces $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} = e$, so that $xy=yx$, hence the elements of $P$ commute with the elements of $Q$. It follows that $\phi$ as I defined above is a homomorphism:
$$\phi((x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2)) = \phi(x_1 x_2, y_1 y_2) = x_1 x_2 y_1 y_2 = x_1 y_1 x_2 y_2 = \phi(x_1,y_1)\phi(x_2,y_2)$$
And the argument proceeds as above.

Well done :-) :-)

Thank you!! Thanks again for the help :)
